Surjectivity of the map $x\mapsto \frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$ on the maximal unramified extension of the $p$-adic numbers
Let $p$ be a prime number and let $\breve{\mathbb Q}_p$ be the completion of the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$. The Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\breve{\mathbb Q}_p/\mathbb Q_p) \simeq \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb F_p}/\mathbb F_p)$ is topologically generated by the Frobenius automorphism $\sigma$, which induces $x\mapsto x^p$ on the residue field.
Can every unit $u \in \mathcal O_{\breve{\mathbb Q}_p}^{\times}$ be written under the form $u = \frac{\sigma(t)}{t}$ for some $t\in \breve{\mathbb Q}_p^{\times}$ ?
It looks like Hilbert's 90 theorem but it isn't quite the same, since I'm not considering norms really. Instead, I guess that I'm asking for the surjectivity of the "Lang map" in the $p$-adic setting.
In cohomological words, I guess that I'm asking whether $H^1(\langle \sigma \rangle, \mathcal O_{\breve{\mathbb Q}_p}^{\times})$ is trivial. Here, $\langle \sigma \rangle := \sigma^{\mathbb Z}$ is the absolute Weil group of $\mathbb Q_p$.
This should be well known, so I would be happy to find a reference for such a statement.

I wouldn't know a reference immediately either, but have you tried a typical devissage argument?

An element of the form $\sigma(t)/t$ for $t \in F^{\times}$ for some finite unramified $F/\mathbb{Q}_p$ has norm one over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. So for instance one never has $p+1=\sigma(t)/t$ for $t \in F^{\times}$, where $F/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is finite unramified. So if $\breve{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ really denotes the maximal (algebraic) unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then the statement is false. However, I suppose you meant that $\breve{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ was the completion of the extension described above, ie the complete discretely valued field with residue field $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$?

@Aphelli I apologize for my late reply. As you point it out, I was thinking about the completion really. I edited my question accordingly.

In this case, I agree with Torsten Schoeneberg that dévissage is the way to go.

@Aphelli I assume that dévissage means, roughly, solving the equation mod $p$, then $p^2$, $p^3$ etc... using Hensel lemma at each step? The corresponding statement mod $p$ does work since the Lang map (here, for $G_m$) is surjective.

That’s indeed what I mean by dévissage (except the equation isn’t polynomial so you can’t invoke Hensel directly). The general statement I suggest is to show that for any $r \geq 1$, $z \in (1+p^r \mathcal{O})/(1+p^{r+1}\mathcal{O}) \mapsto \frac{\sigma(z)}{z} \in (1+p^r \mathcal{O})/(1+p^{r+1}\mathcal{O})$ is onto, where $\mathcal{O}$ is the valuation ring of $\breve{\mathbb{Q}_p}$.
